# Show difference in two text files using minGW diff

Tags: mingw

My objective is to compare two text file using **minGW diff** and the result should be saved in a new text file.

I am using this command in command prompt:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\diff C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\v1.txt C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\v2.txt
```

**v1.txt:**
This is a cat. I hate it.

**V2.txt:**
This is a rat. I like it.
I have a house.

**Output in cmd:**

```
This is a cat. I hate it.                                     \ This is a rat. I
 like it.
                                                              > I have a house.
```

Although it shows the difference, but it does not saves the result in  a new file.
I want to neatly show the difference in some new text file.Can somebody please tell how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (I'm assuming because of MinGW), you can log the output of a command to a textfile with "> log.txt"

eg.

> diff 1.txt 2.txt > log.txt